# What if tree set object change its value (best practice for treeset?)?

Tags: java, treeset

```
List list = new ArrayList();
MyObj mine = new MyObj();
list.add(mine);
```

I like to add object to list before manipulating the object so that i don't forget to add it later, may be i work in crazy enrichment logic where i like this way more

```
mine.setXXX(stuff);
```

This is the way I always used to add objects in a list,

Just now i have a use case where `TreeSet` make more sense, so naturally I wanted to do something like this:-

```
Set set = new TreeSet();
MyObj mine = new MyObj();
set.add(mine);
mine.setXXX(stuff); // add setters here
```

but the issue here is that `Treeset` needs to have variables used in `compareTo` methods to be initialized before adding object to the list.

Ok, I can take care of it.

But my worry and question is:-
Is there a way i can enforce to the developer who may be using my models where I have used `Treeset` to not repeat my mistake. i.e. to enforece them to intiate the `myObject` variables before adding the object to the set.
Though developers should know this and should take care of it, but still is there a way force it or some best practice around that.

Comment: my issue is slighty diffirent i want to have a mechanism to enforce that object is added after getting compareTo variable initialized. though in older question they discuss primary on how to refresh treeset each time object's variable is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not a general way to enforce this. The best way to do so is to put immutable objects in the set only that cannot be modified. Rather than having a `setXXX` method on your object, make it configurable through the constructor and not editable.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: the values for the fields that are mandatory should be passed along in the object's constructor, and never provide a constructor that doesn't include *at least* all the mandatory fields. Then you can set them in the constructor.

Comment: ... and make them final, ideally.

Comment: @leoismyname my pleasure! also, Jon Skeet's advice is sound: if possible, mark the attributes involved in calculating the hash as `final`, so there's no chance to modify them by accident